Normality of a family of functions
This is an exercise of complex analysis I came across.
Determine the biggest $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $3i \in \Gamma$ and such that
$$F:= \{ f_n(z) = \tan(nz) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$
is a normal family. Furthermore find the accumulation point.

My attempt:
I have found that $f_n(z)$ has poles in
$$z_k = \frac{\pi (1 + 2k)}{2n}$$
for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, so my best guess would be that, since we have defined normality on $F \subset C(\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ open and connected, my best guess is that we have to work on
$$3i \in \{ z = x + i y : y > 0\} =: A$$
Furthermore with the above discussion on poles we also have that $F \subset Hol(A)$. Now I would like to use Montel's Theorem: $F \subset Hol(A)$ if and only if it is locally uniformly bounded.
This is where I fail to reach a conclusion.

I was not able to find solved exercises to acquire techniques for such an exercise, also I am not sure about my attempt before wanting to apply Montel's Theorem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Do you mean $f_n(z) = \tan(nz)$?

Yes, edited. Thanks

First note that
$$
\tan z = \frac{\sin z}{\cos z}= -i \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}= -i \frac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1}.
$$
Let $K$ be a compact subset of the upper half plane (you called $A$). Then there is some $m>0$ such that $\forall z=x+iy \in K: ~ m \le y$. Thus, for $z=x+iy \in K$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$: $e^{2inz}= e^{2inx}{e^{-2ny}}$, hence
$$
|\tan(nz)| \le \frac{1+|e^{2inz}|}{1- |e^{2inz}|}= \frac{1+e^{-2ny}}{1-e^{-2ny}} \le \frac{2}{1-e^{-2nm}} \le \frac{2}{1-e^{-2m}}.
$$
Thus $\{f_n:A \to \mathbb{C}\mid f_n(z)=\tan(nz), n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is locally bounded, hence normal. Moreover, for each $z \in A$ we have $e^{2inz} \to 0$ $(n \to \infty)$, thus $(f_n)$ is compact convergent to the constant function $i$ on $A$ which therefore is the only accumulation point.
